# Taking a photo by Intent on android

Tags: android, android-camera

I am trying to take a photo by using an Intent.
My code looks like [this](http://codeviewer.org/view/code:217e) and I don't know where the problem is.
When I want to get my app started, I get error:

```
12-20 06:09:03.243: E/AndroidRuntime(1048): java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.camera.CameraHardwareException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android - Fail to connect to camera](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563973/android-fail-to-connect-to-camera)

Comment: Did you forget permission? <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

Comment: did u give write sd card permission?

Comment: try `rebooting your device` and change your image name to `.temp to .png`

Answer (score 0):

Intent for taking photo is as follows:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

Now in activity result you will get image capture path.

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
      try {


                    File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                            + File.separator + "temp" + File.separator);
                    root.mkdirs();
                    File sdImageMainDirectory = new File(root, "myPicName.jpg");
                     Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(sdImageMainDirectory);
                    startCameraActivity();
                } catch (Exception e) {

                    Toast.makeText(this, "Error occured. Please try again later.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
    protected void startCameraActivity() {



            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 101);


        }

@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode==101 && resultCode==-1)
        {
            try
            {
            //   "/mnt/sdcard/temp/myPicName.jpg" is ur image file if u want to use it
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {



            }
        }
```