# Open front camera in all android devices

Tags: android, camera

I am unable to get a logic on using front camera by default in every android devices. In my app. i need to open a front camera automatically on capture image button and after image capture it should be store directly to local database of my application instead of SD card. 
Any idea ??

Comment: What have you tried? Have you [tried the code here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4767832/1270789)?

Comment: Yes Ken, it was my first attempt. But getting an error "unable to connect camera services"

Comment: Here's [an SE question on that error message](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563973/android-fail-to-connect-to-camera). Please check all five answers to see if any apply to your problem.